# why is there an unexpected unicode control character in windows 8.1 filepath

Tags: windows, unicode

I'm coding a md5 program . The program works well for the string ,so i went to  md5 file test.Then everything went beyond my expectation. I copyed the the file path with these steps:

1. select the file and right click
2. open the property tab the switch to the security tab
3. copy the filepath to my code ,edit the backslash stuff 
   [image: how i copy and paste]

But the program  said that it couldn't find the file .When i moved the file to the current workspace and manually type the filename ,the program sometimes worked while complained for the file not found . It worked ,i don't why.It didn't work, i don't know why .

Confused as i was,i tried to figure out what's wrong and that wasted my day.The i asked someone for help .I sent the source file to my friend .He opened it with vim ,found some suspicious character in the filepath. The suspicious character is :<202a> .After deleted the <202a>, my program worked .Holy crap!

I asked him to get the filepath as i did. But the program still worked .This time i felt like a dumbass. So i get a filepath on my machine as the instruction i just said ,my program reported file not found as before. After some futile trial ,i can see there is an invisible bar at the begin of the path . So that invisible bar was the trouble maker.

So there come the questions:

4. why there is an unexpected unicode contol character at te begin of path?
5. why win 8.1 has this issue while win7 doesn't?
6. how can i disable the nauseous feature on win8.1?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It might have nothing to do with the version of Windows and everything to do with your language settings.

Comment: U+202A is the Left-to-right embedding control character.  You cannot see it, it only affects how the subsequent text is rendered.  Left-to-right.  How it ended up in your string is unguessable from the question, your IME probably has something to do with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [0x202A in filename: Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037882/0x202a-in-filename-why)

Comment: @RaymondChen That is it . But there isn't a solution . I hate to manually type the file path.....

Comment: You have to manually delete the invisible U+202A.